# Javascript Calculate age given year of birth

Tags: javascript, html

In learning Javascript, am trying to alert user the object contents, the first three are display but the function age part with function is not, please assist

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
 <head>
  <script>
   var person = {fname: "Asha",lname: "Juma",dob: 2005,age:function(){(new Date().getFullYear() - this.dob);}};

   function print() {
    alert(JSON.stringify(person));
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>Lets hit this button to alert the user of the person object contents</p>
  <button onclick=print()>Click Me!</button>
  
 </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: In your output, are you expecting to see the code of the `age` function, or the result of a call to it?

Comment: The result like age:12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With an object literal, as you have it, this should work:

```
var person = {fname: "Asha",lname: "Juma",dob: 2005,age:(new Date().getFullYear() - 2005)};
```

If you are only going to work with a single person object, the object literal is good, however, you must put the birth year in twice.

If you would like to create more people, use a constructor function.

```
function Person(fname,lname,dob){
    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname;
    this.dob = dob;
}
Person.prototype.age = function(){
    this.age = new Date().getFullYear() - this.dob;
}

var person = new Person('First','Last',2004);
```

The prototype allows you to add the method age to each instance of Person.

If you are learning, try using the console.log method to display the output in the web inspector.  For example:

```
console.log(person);
```

Comment: The object literal is giving me "age": null

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the `this.dob` property because the object is still not created.
So check below code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
 <head>
  <script>
   var person = {fname: "Asha",lname: "Juma",dob: 2005};
      person.age =  (new Date().getFullYear()-person.dob);

   function print() {
    alert(JSON.stringify(person));
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>Lets hit this button to alert the user of the person object contents</p>
  <button onclick=print()>Click Me!</button>
  
 </body>
    </html>
```